# Google Cloud documentation misleading

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

On [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/getting_started) link, under "Deploying, Downloading, and Running the Sample", point 6, it is stated this:

> "In the upper left, locate the two small dots under the sample app icon, and click the second dot to switch to the Mobile Backend sample".

Following the steps so far, there is no "upper left two small dots" or "sample app icon"..

Is the documentation obsolete with some changes that are being done on the Cloud Console or am I missing something here.. also there is no [easy] way to delete Projects, what is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that, we made a few changes to the console.   You can find information about the Mobile Backend Starter here: https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the second part of your question:

> also there is no [easy] way to delete Projects, what is this?

From the Google Cloud Console for your project (if you've selected your project under the top-left drop-down menu), under "Settings" there's a "Delete Project" option.

Comment: Edited to remove my further question, leaving just the answer to the OP's secondary query.