# Google Cloud Platform backend deployment documentation still misleading

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following the Google Cloud Platform instructions to Deploy the Backend. I've followed things through to the [Enable Push](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/enable_push) page, but I'm stuck on the following instructions:

> 9 Return to the Google Cloud Console for your Mobile Backend project.
>
> 10 Click Settings.
>
> 11 Click Mobile Backend Starter within this project. It should be located at the bottom of the page.

The Settings page, linked from my Google Cloud Console page, has only "Delete Project" and "Rename Project" as its options; there's no link to "Mobile Backend Starter".

I believe these instructions have been updated in the past couple of days in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549905/google-cloud-documentation-misleading) question, but it looks like they're now incorrect in a different way. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: Also, the subsequent instructions don't actually appear to be telling me to do anything, just to click on "Settings" and then "Save". Save what? (I *think* the older instructions had mentioned to paste the API key into a box... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies on the mix-up. You are correct; there should be a line of instruction to tell you to copy your API Key. What the last few instructions (replacing #9 onwards) should be:

> 1. Navigate to {your-project-id}.appspot.com. This will bring you to your Mobile Backend Starter settings configuration page.
> 2. Under Google Cloud Messaging and iOS Push Notification, toggle the radio button to "Enabled". Copy your API Key from the clipboard into the text box provided.
> 3. Click Save.

The documentation will be updated.